# Access one image of dataset obtained with tfds.load()

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I download my dataset like this: `dataset = tfds.load('cifar10', split='train', shuffle_files=True)`. After applying the `batch()` method I have that **dataset** is:

`Attributes of object: {'image': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(128, 32, 32, 3) dtype=uint8>, 'label': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>}`

If I use `next(iter(train_dataset))` or `for elem in train_dataset.take(1): print (elem.numpy())` I need `eager_execution`.

If I try `dataset[image]`, I get that the object is not subscriptable.

If I try with:

```py
iterator=dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  next_val = iterator.get_next()
  print(f'my_image: {next_val}')
  print(f'my_image: {next_val['image']}')
```

I get:

```
    print(f'my_image: {next_val['image']}')
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even if I enable eager execution and do `batch = iter(dataset).get_next()` I get

```
Attributes of object: {'image': <tf.Tensor: id=156, shape=(128, 32, 32, 3), dtype=uint8, numpy=
array([[[[ 53,  53,  60],
         [ 63,  62,  66],
         [ 74,  72,  75],
         ...,
         [187, 194, 232],
```

but I can't access the single image.

EDIT: I'm using tensorflow 1.15.5

Comment: Any updates on solution? Did you find any useful code that can answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

You can access the batched array with:

```
dataset.x
```

where it will have shape `(num_of_images, rows, cols, channel)`.

If you want a single image, you can treat it as an array (because it is):

```
first_image = dataset.x[0]
last_image = dataset.x[-1]

pyplot.plt.axis("off")
pyplot.imshow(first_image)
```

**Edit:** Additionally, you can get the corresponding array of labels with:

```
dataset.y
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object has no attribute 'x'`. What's `x`?

Comment: That's weird, when I make datasets using `Dataset` and debug, they contain `x` and `y` ndarrays... Yours doesn't when you debug and look at the dataset?

Comment: did you loaded the dataset with `pandas`?

Comment: Nah, I mostly work with image data (nothing mixed) so I just use arrays. You should still be able to step through the code while it's running and see the contents on your 'Dataset'.